# send message to active tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am using `executeScript` to run in the current active tab. But inside its callback function I want to send a message to the script being executed...

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'src/js/scripts/extractCSS.js'
     }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(this.props.source);
```

`this.props.source` is an object I am trying to pass. And inside `src/js/scripts/extractCSS.js` I am trying to catch the message...

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
     console.log(message);
});
```

However I get the following error...

```
Error in response to tabs.executeScript: Error: Invocation 
of form tabs.sendMessage(object) doesn't match definition 
tabs.sendMessage(integer tabId, any message, optional object 
options, optional function responseCallback)
```

From what I gather, I need to define `tabId`, but I just need to send the message to the active tab. I tried adding `null` for `tabId` but it still gives me an error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though its a active tab, you will have to pass the `tabId`. `chrome.tabs.query` can be used to get the tabs. You can do it the following way:

```
chrome.tabs.query(
    { currentWindow: true, active: true },
    function (tabArray) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabArray[0].id, {
            file: 'src/js/scripts/extractCSS.js'
         }, function() {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(this.props.source);

        })
    }
);
```

As there can be only one active tab in current window, `tabArray` will have one element only and then `id` attribute can be accessed.